# What is the use or importance of square roots in solidity and in blockchain in general?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, math, safemath

I have been seeing many posts about different implementations of finding the square root of a number with regard to blockchain and there is an edit in this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296102/fastest-square-root-algorithm referring to smart contract engineers. What exactly is their importance in blockchain and why is it so hard?

Answer (score 1):

It just happens to be a difficult mathematical operation to implement in an environment with certain restrictions, such as Ethereum smart contracts, which don't support floating point arithmetics (decimals).

So, as far as I can tell, it's not a super interesting or super essential function to have, but it just happens to be a function which is difficult to implement and has therefore open questions.

Furthermore, smart contracts require efficiency. The question you linked is specifically asking about efficient solutions.